Best way to construct random Matrix with constraints
I am looking to construct a (real) matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of shape $M*N$ ( with $M \geq N$) which fulfils the following constraints:
$$
||\mathbf{A}||^2 = \sum_\mu^M \sum_\nu^N \mathbf{A}_{\mu\nu}^2 = N\\
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^\intercal = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^\intercal \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^\intercal
$$
I am aware that one way of constructing such a matrix would be to start with a zero-matrix and place a 1 in a different row for each column. E.g. for a $3*2$ case, this would be a solution:
$$
\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
However, I would like to find a way of constructing more of these matrices, and using more than 0s and 1s.
As I intend to use them as test cases for a program, I'd ideally like a way to construct them as randomly as possible.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

$
\def\R{{\mathbb R}^{m\times n}}
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
$Start with a random matrix $X\in\R$ and construct a semi-orthogonal matrix $A\in\R$
$$\eqalign{
A &= X\big(X^TX\big)^{-1/2}
 &\qiq AA^T = X\big(X^TX\big)^{-1}X^T \\
&&\qiq A^T\!A = I_n \\
}$$
First check the idempotent constraint
$$\eqalign{
\big(AA^T\big)^2
 \;=\; A\big(A^T\!A\big)A^T \;=\; AA^T \\
}$$
Then check the norm constraint
$$\eqalign{
\big\|A\big\|_F^2
 \;=\; \operatorname{Tr}(A^TA) 
 \;=\; \operatorname{Tr}(I_n) 
 \;=\; n \\
}$$
This is not the only solution to your problem, but it is probably the simplest.

Although I've written the construction in terms of the inverse and square root, it may be simpler to use a Newton iteration,
e.g. here's a Julia code snippet
A = rand(m,n)
A = A/norm(A)    # initialize
for k = 1:30
    E = I-A'A    # residual
    A = A+A*E/2  # update
    if norm(E) < 1e-12
       break
    end
end

